# Why is my method not working from my vue.js component

Tags: vue.js, components

Can't call a method in the vue.js main component from a vue.js sub component

Method from the main Vue.js component:

```
var studyInfo = new Vue({
 el: '#examInfo',
 methods: {
  deleteComment: function () {
      alert("I an in main component");
  }
```

Child component:

```
Vue.component('multilabels-note',
    {
        props: ['label', 'label2', 'note'],
        template: '<div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">' +
            '<div class= "d-flex w-100 justify-content-between" >' +
            '<h5 class="mb-1" style="color:#0080FF" v-if="note.isComment">{{ note.noteHeader }}Comment</h5>' +
            '<p class="mb-1">{{ note.text }}</p>' +
            '<small>{{ note && note.author && note.author.name }}</small>' +
            '<button v-if="note.isComment" id="btnComment" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right" v-on:click="deleteComment">Delete</button>' +
            '</div>',
        methods: { formatDateTime: formatDateTime }
        }
    }
);
```

From my index.cshtml:

```
 <multilabels-note v-for="note in techNotes" :note="note"></multilabels-note>
```

When I click on the Delete button from the child component nothing happened.
if I changed the button from the child component to like this, nothing happened neither

```
   '<button v-if="note.isComment" id="btnComment" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right" v-on:click="$emit(deleteComment)">Delete</button>' +
```

I can use some help here. Please tell me what I have done wrong here. What am I missing?

Every thing seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for child template and listen to event:

```js
Vue.component('multilabelsNote', {
  props: ['label', 'label2', 'note'],
  template: `
    <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
      <div class= "d-flex w-100 justify-content-between" >
        <h5 class="mb-1" style="color:#0080FF" v-if="note.isComment">{{ note.noteHeader }} Comment</h5>
        <p class="mb-1">{{ note.text }}</p>
        <small>{{ note && note.author && note.author.name }}</small>
        <button v-if="note.isComment" id="btnComment" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right" @click="$emit('del', note.id)">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>`,
});
var studyInfo = new Vue({
  el: '#examInfo',
  data() {
    return {
      techNotes: [{id: 1, isComment: true, text: '1', noteHeader: 'A', author: {name: 'A'}}, {id: 2, isComment: false, text: '2', noteHeader: 'B', author: {name: 'B'}}, {id: 3, isComment: true, text: '3', noteHeader: 'C', author: {name: 'C'}}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    deleteComment(id) {
      alert("I an in main component - " + id)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="examInfo">
  <multilabels-note v-for="(note, i) in techNotes" :note="note" :key="i" @del="deleteComment"></multilabels-note>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer for the most part solved my issue, thank you. The weird thing is if I used @del = 'deleteComment' then I got an error saying "the name del does not exist in the current context' but it is ok if I used v-on:del

Comment: I got it working using template literals but It only worked in Chrome and Edge and failed in IE.  So how do i define this line in my vue.js component without using template literal: <button v-if="note.isRadiologistComment" id="btnDeleteRadiologistComment" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right" @click="$emit('del', note.radiologyNoteId, note.noteVersionId)">Delete</button>